# Form saves data to database and them reloads itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form in my client.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/client.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="chatBox">
        <div class="chatBoxHead">Chat with Support</div>
        <div class="contentArea" style="display: none">
          <div class="formArea">
            <div class="title">Please fill out this form</div>
            <form class="loginForm" id="loginForm">
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input class="nameInput" type="text" placeholder=" * Name" name="name" id="name" required />
              </div>
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <label for="email"></label>
                <input class="emailInput" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder=" * Email" required />
              </div>
              <button class="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="chatArea" style="display: none">
            <div class="messages">
              <div class="oldMsg"></div>
              <div class="newMsg"></div>
            </div>
            <div class='typing'></div>
            <input class="inputMessage" rows="1" placeholder="Type here..."></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I click on the submit button for the login form, it saves the data to the database and then reloads itself as opposed to saving the data and then displaying the chat area for messaging. Here is my client.js file

```
var $window = $(window);
var socket = io(); 
var $messages = $('.messages'); 
var $inputMessage = $('.inputMessage');  
var $nameInput = $('.nameInput'); 
var $emailInput = $('.emailInput'); 
var $formArea = $('.formArea'); 
var $contentArea = $('.contentArea'); 
var $login = $('#loginForm'); 
var $chatArea = $('.chatArea'); 
var $typing = $(".typing"); 
var $oldMsg = $('.oldMsg'); 
var $newMsg = $('.newMsg');  
var typing = false; 
var timeout = undefined; 
var id = localStorage.getItem("roomID"); 
var active = sessionStorage.getItem('active');  

if (active && id) {
  $formArea.hide();
  $chatArea.show();
  socket.emit('add user', {
    isNewUser: false,
    roomID: id
  });
  $contentArea.show();
}


$('.chatBoxHead').click(function() {
  $contentArea.slideToggle('slow');
  if (id != null && !active) {
    socket.emit('add user', {
      isNewUser: false,
      roomID: id
    });
    $formArea.hide();
    $chatArea.show();
    $inputMessage.focus();
    sessionStorage.setItem('active', true);
    active = true;
  }
});

$login.submit(function() {
  $chatArea.show();
  $formArea.hide();
  $inputMessage.focus();
  sessionStorage.setItem('active', true);
  socket.emit('add user', {
    isNewUser: true,
    Name: $nameInput.val().trim(),
    Email: $emailInput.val().trim()
  });
});


$inputMessage.keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which !== 13) {
    if (typing === false && $inputMessage.is(":focus")) {
      typing = true;
      socket.emit("typing", {
        isTyping: true,
        roomID: id,
        person: "Client"
      });
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 2000);
    }
  } else {
    sendMessage();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeoutFunction();
  }
})

socket.on('chat message', function(data) {
  var sender;
  if (data.isAdmin){
    sender = "msg_admin"
  }
  else{
    sender = "msg_client"
  }
  var $messageBodyDiv = $('<div class="' + sender + '">' + data.message + '<span class="timestamp">' +
    ((data.timestamp).toLocaleString().substr(15, 6)) + '</span></div>').insertBefore($newMsg);
  $messages[0].scrollTop = $messages[0].scrollHeight;
});

function sendMessage() {
  var message = $inputMessage.val();
  // Prevent markup from being injected into the message
  var encodedMessage = $('<div />').text(message).html();
  message = encodedMessage;
  if (message) {
    $inputMessage.val('');
    var time = ("" + new Date().getTime());
    socket.emit('chat message', {
      roomID: "null",
      message: message,
      timestamp: time
    });   
    var $messageBodyDiv = $('<div class="msg_client">' + message + '<span class="timestamp">' +
      (time.toLocaleString().substr(15, 6)) + '</span></div>').insertBefore($newMsg);
    $messages[0].scrollTop = $messages[0].scrollHeight;
  }
}

function timeoutFunction() {
  typing = false;
  socket.emit("typing", {
    isTyping: false,
    roomID: id,
    person: "Client"
  });
}

$messages.on("scroll", function() {
  if ($messages.scrollTop() == 0)
    socket.emit("more messages", {});
})

socket.on('roomID', function(roomID) {
  id = roomID;
  localStorage.setItem("roomID", roomID);
});

socket.on('typing', function(data) {
  if (data.isTyping && data.person != 'Client')
    $Typing.append("Support is typing...");
  else
    $Typing.text('');
});

socket.on('chat history', function(data) {
  var len = data.history.length;
  for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    addMessages(data.history[i], false);
});

socket.on('more chat history', function(data) {
  var len = data.history.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    addMessages(data.history[i], true);
});

function addMessages(data, getMore) {
  var sender;
  if (data["who"]){
    sender = "msg_admin"
  }
  else{
    sender = "msg_client"
  }
  var $messageBodyDiv = $('<div class="' + sender + '">' + data["message"] + '<span class="timestamp">' +
    (data["timeStamp"]).toLocaleString().substr(15, 6) + '</span></div>');
  if (getMore) {
    $messageBodyDiv.insertAfter($oldMsg);
    $messages[0].scrollTop += $messageBodyDiv.outerHeight();
  } else {
    $messageBodyDiv.insertBefore($newMsg);
    $messages[0].scrollTop = $messages[0].scrollHeight;
  }
}

socket.on('log message', function(text) {
  var time = ("" +  new Date().getTime());
  var $messageDiv = $('<div class="msg_admin">' + text + '<span class="timestamp">' +
    (time.toLocaleString().substr(15, 6)) + '</span></div>').insertBefore($newMsg);
  $messages[0].scrollTop = $messages[0].scrollHeight;
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log("Disconnected!");
  $inputMessage.prop('disabled', true);
  $inputMessage.prop('placeholder', "Connection Lost! Reconnecting..");
});

socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
  console.log("Reconnection Failed!");
  $inputMessage.prop('placeholder', "No active connection. Please refresh page.");
});

socket.on('reconnect', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Reconnected!");
    $inputMessage.prop('disabled', false);
    $inputMessage.prop('placeholder', "Type here...");
    if (active && id)
      socket.emit('add user', {
        isNewUser: false,
        roomID: id
      });
  }, 10000);
});
```

Also here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var uuid = require('uuid');
var config = require(__dirname + "/config.js");
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var _ = require("underscore");
var db = require('./controllers/db');
var btoa = require('btoa');
var users = {};
var admins = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret: "luxtag chat",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Setup rethinkDB database
db.setupDB();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/client.html');
});

app.get(config.rethinkdb.admin_url, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/admin.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(`Socket ID: ${socket.id}`);
  console.dir(socket.handshake, {colors: true});


  //Admin login
  socket.on('login', function(data) {
    if (btoa(data.password) != config.rethinkdb.key)
      socket.emit('login', {
        login: false,
        err: "Invalid Login"
      })
    else {
      if (_.find(config.rethinkdb.admin_users, function(admin) {
          return (admin == data.admin);
        })) {
        if (admins[data.admin]) {
          socket.emit('login', {
            login: false,
            err: "Already Logged In"
          })
        } else {
          socket.emit('login', {
            login: true
          })
        }
      } else {
        socket.emit('login', {
          login: false,
          err: "Invalid Login"
        })
      }
    }
  });

  socket.on('add admin', function(data) {
    this.isAdmin = data.isAdmin;
    socket.username = data.admin;
    console.log('admins: ', admins);
    console.log('users: ', users);
    _.each(admins, function(adminSocket) {
      adminSocket.emit("admin added", socket.username)
      socket.emit("admin added", adminSocket.username)
    });

    admins[socket.username] = socket;

    //If some user is already online on chat
    if (Object.keys(users).length > 0) {
      _.each(users, function(userSocket) {
        db.getMessages(userSocket.roomID, 0)
          .then(function(history) {
            var len = history.length;
            var userSocket = users[history[len - 1]];
            history.splice(-1, 1);
            socket.join(userSocket.roomID);
            socket.emit("New Client", {
              roomID: userSocket.roomID,
              history: history,
              details: userSocket.userDetails,
              justJoined: true
            })
          })
      });
    }
  }); 

  socket.on('add user', function(data) {
    socket.isAdmin = false;
    if (data.isNewUser) {
      data.roomID = uuid.v4();
      var user = {
        id: data.roomID,
        name: data.Name,
        email: data.Email
      }
      console.log(user);
      db.saveUser(user, function (saved, err) {
        if (saved) {
          console.log('user saved...');
          return;
        }
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error creating the account');
        }
        else {
          console.log("The account wasn't created");
        }
      });
      socket.emit("roomID", data.roomID);
    }
    socket.roomID = data.roomID;
    console.log('socket.roomID: ', socket.roomID);
    //get user 
    db.findUserById(socket.roomID, function(err, details) {
      if(err){
        console.log("Line 60 : ", error);
      }
      else {
        socket.userDetails = details;
        console.log('socket.userDetails: ', socket.userDetails);
      }
    });
    socket.join(socket.roomID);
    var newUser = false;
    if (!users[socket.roomID]) {  
      users[socket.roomID] = socket;
      newUser = true;
    }
    //get message history
    db.getMessages(socket.roomID, 0)
      .then(function(history) {
        history.splice(-1, 1)
        socket.emit('chat history', {
          history: history,
          getMore: false
        });
        if (Object.keys(admins).length == 0) {
          //Tell user he will be contacted asap 
          socket.emit('log message', "Thank you for reaching us." +
            " Please leave your message here and we will get back to you shortly.");
        } else {
          if (newUser) {
            socket.emit('log message', "Hello " + socket.userDetails['name'] + ", How can I help you?");
            //Make all available admins join this users room.
            _.each(admins, function(adminSocket) {
              adminSocket.join(socket.roomID);
              adminSocket.emit("New Client", {
                roomID: socket.roomID,
                history: history,
                details: socket.userDetails,
                justJoined: false
              })
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Line 113 : ", error)
      })
      .done();
    db.getMsgLength(socket.roomID)
      .then(function(len) {
        socket.MsgHistoryLen = (len * -1) + 10;
        socket.TotalMsgLen = (len * -1);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Line 121 : ", error)
      })
      .done();
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(data){
    if (data.roomID === "null"){
      data.roomID = socket.roomID;
    }
    data.isAdmin = socket.isAdmin;
    var msg = {
      who: data.isAdmin,
      message: data.message,
      timestamp: data.timestamp
    }

    db.saveMessage(msg, function (err, saved) {
      if (err || !saved) {
        console.log('There was an error saving your message');
        return;
      }
      socket.broadcast.to(data.roomID).emit('chat message', data);
    });
  });

  socket.on("typing", function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.to(data.roomID).emit("typing", {
      isTyping: data.isTyping,
      person: data.person,
      roomID: data.roomID
    });
  });

  socket.on("more messages", function() {
    if (socket.MsgHistoryLen < 0) {
      db.getMessages(socket.roomID, socket.MsgHistoryLen)
        .then(function(history) {
          history.splice(-1, 1)
          socket.emit('more chat history', {
            history: history
          });
        })
      socket.MsgHistoryLen += 10;
    }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    if (socket.isAdmin) {
      delete admins[socket.username];
      _.each(admins, function(adminSocket) {
        adminSocket.emit("admin removed", socket.username)
      });
    } else {
      if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomID]) {
        var total = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomID]["length"];
        var totAdmins = Object.keys(admins).length;
        var clients = total - totAdmins;
        if (clients == 0) {
          //check if user reconnects in 10 seconds 
          setTimeout(function() {
            if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomID]){
              total = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomID]["length"];
            }
            totAdmins = Object.keys(admins).length;
            if (total <= totAdmins) {
              delete users[socket.roomID];
              socket.broadcast.to(socket.roomID).emit("User Disconnected", socket.roomID);
              _.each(admins, function(adminSocket) {
                adminSocket.leave(socket.roomID)
              });
            }
          }, 10000);
        }
      } else {
        if (socket.userDetails)
        delete users[socket.roomID];
      }
    }
  });
});

http.listen(config.express.port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + config.express.port);
});
```

**any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: That's the default behaviour to reload the page itself when submiting a `form`. If you doesn't want it, use: `<button type="button" class="submit" >Submit</button>`

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried doing that, but then when I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: @Nicolas when I click on the submit button I want it to save the data (which it is doing) and then hide the login form and then display the chat area form for messaging.

Comment: Then use ajax, not a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a submit function in your `js` that does the `POST` request to the server and prevent the default behavior. `jQuery` example:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do post request here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposing, you get a `success promise` after data stored in database successfully.

You need to prevent automatic form submission. Look out below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="return toSubmit();">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" >
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form> 

<script>
   function toSubmit(){
     if(document.getElementById('name').value == "tushar"){
      alert("success");
      return true;
     }
     else{
        alert("failed");
        return false;
     }
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```